# Why did members of The One Sith in Prisoner of the Floating World have no tattoos

Tags: star-wars, comics

All members of [The One Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars%3a_Legacy_1%3a_Prisoner_of_the_Floating_World,_Part_1) had tattoos, yet the master who ambushed [Yalta Val](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yalta_Val) in the Surd Nebula and his human apprentice had no tattoos. It's possible that the two could have removed them to increase secrecy when the One Sith were on the down-low, but wouldn't they be hard to remove?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that because the new canon is different where the idea of the One Sith tattoos are based on Darth Maul's. Later they retconned this in the Clone Wars animated tv series and they became 'Nightbrother tattoos', which changed the idea that Darth Maul's tattoos were that of the Sith, which they're not.

Answer (score -3):

For stealth and it was deemed strange in later issues of Legacy.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this answer, maybe cite issues or explain how it was deemed strange?